# How to check if a key vault name is available or not using bash cli?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create an Azure Key Vault but I am getting below error:

`az keyvault create --location ${regionName} --name ${MyKeyVault} --resource-group ${resourceGroupName}`

Error: (VaultAlreadyExists) The name 'check' is already in use.

Please help me write a code to check if the Key Vault name is avaialable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in CLI command to do this, your option is to use [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest) call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/checknameavailability) directly.

**Sample:**

```
az rest --method post --uri 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/checkNameAvailability?api-version=2019-09-01' --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body '{"name": "joykeyvault","type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"}'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure API to check that Keyvault name is valid and is not already in use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/checknameavailability

Comment: I was looking for some cli command like we have for storage account etc. something like below:
`az storage account check-name --name $storageAccount`

Comment: Do @Joy Wang's Answer give you more clarity?